# Cosider address : get the part of address

Tags: asp.net

get the part of address with asp web form
Cosider address :

`http://Example.com/Main/CategoryTechnology/CSS-CSS3/#123/Page`

I want to get Number 123 with asp.net web forms
Please help me..Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
string num = Regex.Match(Request.RawUrl.ToString(), @"/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)").Groups[4].Value.Replace('#','');
```

NOTE: Check for null values properly

Comment: thak you for reply ..                                                                     this line has error : error -> system.text.regularexpressions.group dose not contain a define for replace

Comment: system.text.regularexpressions.group dose not contain a define for replace

Comment: I have edited the statement with .Value.Replace('#','');. Try that